# Creating a web app from Jupyter Output Interface using Django or React?

Tags: python, reactjs, django, jupyter-notebook, web-applications

I am working on a project for a research group where I have to create a web app for this tool, [AdaTest](https://github.com/microsoft/adatest/tree/main). Currently, the tools runs on a jupyter notebook, where an interface pops up and the user can interact with the tool to approve and deny tests for machine learning models. I want to essentially port this interface onto a web app. Any thoughts on the best way to go about doing this? Or would I have to essentially reinvent the tool altogether to make this work?

I've tried using the repl_html method to generate a html script, and then using Django to render that html code as a HttpResponse. However, the tool did not work as anticipated and the tests did not render.

I've also thought about directly moving the kernel of the notebook into a web app, making the whole kernel the interface. However, I have no idea where to begin with that.

Any suggestions are appreciated!